# Deleting files only in sub-folders using bat script

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting

I am trying to delete files present in a nested sub-directory of Jenkins home directory but not anything outside the nested sub-directory.

Here is the directory structure.

```
└───Jenkins_Home
    └───Jobs
        ├───Job1
        │   │   ot1.xml
        │   │
        │   └───fileParams
        │           sample1.war
        │
        ├───Job2
        │       ot2.xml
        │
        └───Job3
            │   ot3.xml
            │
            └───fileParams
                    sample2.war
```

The files I want to delete are `sample1.war` & `sample2.war` but not `ot1.xml`,  `ot2.xml` and `ot3.xml`.

I tried the following methods, but those methods are deleting every *.txt file.

**Method1:**

```
cd C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\**\fileParams
del /s /q *.war
```

**Method2:**

```
cd C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\**\**
del /s /q *.war
```

**Method3:**

```
cd C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\**
del /s /q *.war
```

There are almost 100 such directory structures, and I don't want to resort to manual methods.

What's the correct way/script to match the above requirements?

> **PS:** I want to run this job every night using cron schedule in Jenkins. Due to audit purpose I can’t delete jobs, but I can delete the built artifacts to keep jenkins home directory light.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I have updated my question. I want to delete only the nested sub-directory files. Not the other ones.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard In job1, job2, etc there is fileParams directory. Only the contents in this directory must be deleted, and its name is same across jobs. PS: some jobs don’t have fileParams folder.

Comment: So in short then after your edit, you want to delete all `.war` files? Perhaps something simple in the lines of:
`for /R "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\" %%i in (*.war) do echo %%i`

Comment: I've no idea what the aim of the `**` elements in your `cd` commands is. For me, if `cd ....directory\**` is executed, the current directory is changed to `....directory`. Executing the `del /s /q *.war` command from there *should* delete all of the `.war` files below `jobs`, so each of these methods *should* work, even given the illogical `cd` instruction. Is the current drive correct - if it isn't, then the `*.war` files *should* be deleted on the current drive. You say *all* files are being deleted? I'd try `del /s /q "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\*.war"

Comment: @Magoo Since there are subdirectories in jobs folder, I used ** to denote those sub folders

Comment: Naturally, try my suggestion on a dummy directory first. Are you giving us the *actual* directory(-tree) in question, of obfuscating the name? That could be important if the *actual* name contains spaces - and is the reason for the quotes around the target filemask I suggested.

Comment: @Magoo though I have obfuscated the names, but the original folders don’t have spaces between them

Comment: Need to know *precisely* what commands you are using.

Comment: @Magoo I have mentioned about the three methods which I had used to rm -r war files.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard yes, I want to delete war files and the fileParams folder doesn’t have anything apart from war file. Other folders don’t have war files. They only have xml files

Comment: Have you *tried* `del /s /q "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\*.war"` (note missing backslash from original comment)

Comment: @Magoo The command in your comment doesn’t include jobs1, jobs2...jobsN folders inside jobs folder. War files are present in jobs/job1/fileParams/*.war path

Comment: This is true, but irrelevant.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I am working out your suggestion. Please give me 10-15 mins :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard It worked mate. Thank you so much. Now jenkins home will be light :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cmd line use :

```
for /R "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs" %A in (fileParams) do @if exist "%A\*.war" @echo Del %A\*.war
```

In a batch file

```
@Echo off
for /R "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs" %%A in (fileParams
    ) do if exist "%%A\*.war" echo Del %%A\*.war
```

sample output :

```
Del C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\Job1\fileParams\*.war
Del C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\Job3\fileParams\*.war
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `echo`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard That could be read several ways, there are job\job* subfolders without fileParams (that not neccessarily ***do** contain *.war files) -or- there and these war files should/shouldn't be deleted. But you are right - I'm repeating what is already mentioned in (growing list of) comments.

Comment: your solution has also worked. There is a typo in your command. There is dot after fileParams. `for /R "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs" %%A in (fileParams.
    ) do if exist "%%A\*.war" echo Del %%A\*.war`. Please remove the dot.

Comment: As folders usually don't have extensions, the dot shouldn't harm.I'll remove it nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you only have `.war` files in the directory you intend to delete them from, you can just run a `for /R` loop to recurse from the highest folder `jobs` containing the relevant directories:

```
@echo off
for /R "C:\Users\Kris\Desktop\MINE\Jenkins_home\jobs\" %%i in (*.war) do echo del /Q "%%~fi"
```

Simply remove `echo` once you are confident that have the output on screen you require.

Comment: The script is looping through each folder and it is deleting only war files. It is working as intended. Cheers mate!